# Reducer/Context Api

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux

So I have a Context created with reducer. In reducer I have some logic, that in theory should work. I have Show Component that is iterating the data from data.js and has a button.I also have a windows Component that is iterating the data. Anyway the problem is that when I click on button in Show Component it should remove the item/id of data.js in Windows Component and in Show Component, but when I click on it nothing happens. I would be very grateful if someone could help me. Kind regards

````
App.js 

const App =()=>{

   const[isShowlOpen, setIsShowOpen]=React.useState(false)

   const Show = useRef(null)

    function openShow(){
      setIsShowOpen(true)
    }
    function closeShowl(){
      setIsShowOpen(false)
    }


const handleShow =(e)=>{
      if(show.current&& !showl.current.contains(e.target)){
        closeShow() 
      }
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        document.addEventListener('click',handleShow)
          return () =>{
           document.removeEventListener('click', handleShow)
          }   
      },[])
 return (
  <div>

  <div ref={show}>
    <img  className='taskbar__iconsRight'  onClick={() => 
     setIsShowOpen(!isShowOpen)} 
       src="https://winaero.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Control- 
        -icon.png"/>
          {isShowOpen ? <Show  closeShow={closeShow}  />: null}
   </div>
)
}
```Context```
import React, { useState, useContext, useReducer, useEffect } from 'react'
import {windowsIcons} from './data'
import reducer from './reducer'

const AppContext = React.createContext()

const initialState = {
icons: windowsIcons
}

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)

  const remove = (id) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'REMOVE', payload: id })
  }
 
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{ 
        ...state,
        remove,       
      }}
      >
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useGlobalContext = () => {
  return useContext(AppContext)
}

export { AppContext, AppProvider }



reducer.js
const reducer = (state, action) => {  
    if (action.type === 'REMOVE') {
      return {
        ...state,
        icons: state.icons.filter((windowsIcons) => windowsIcons.id !== action.payload),
      }
    }
}

export default reducer

``data.js```
export const windowsIcons =[
  { 
     id:15,
     url:"something/",
     name:"yes",
     img:"/images/icons/crud.png",
    },
    {
        id:16,
        url:"something/",
        name:"nine",
        img:"/images/icons/stermm.png",
       },
       {
        id:17,
        url:"domething/",
        name:"ten",
        img:"/images/icons/ll.png",
       },
       {
        id:18,
        url:"whatever",
        name:"twenty",
        img:"/images/icons/icons848.png",
       },
       {
        id:19,
        url:"hello",
        name:"yeaa",
        img:"/images/icons/icons8-96.png",
       },
    ]


``` Show Component```
import React from 'react'
import { useGlobalContext } from '../../context'
import WindowsIcons from '../../WindowsIcons/WindowsIcons'
const Show = () => {
  const { remove, } = useGlobalContext() 

    return (
        <div className='control'>
          {windowsIcons.map((unin)=>{       
            const { name, img, id} = unin  
            return (             
             <li className='control' key ={id}>
               <div className='img__text'> 
               <img className='control__Img' src={img} />             
                <h4 className='control__name'>{name}</h4>
               </div>
                <button className='unin__button' onClick={() => remove(id)} >remove</button>                 
              </li> )
        </div>
    )
}

export default Show


import React from 'react'
import {windowsIcons} from "../data"
import './WindowsIcons.css'
const WindowsIcons = ({id, url, img, name}) => {
    return (
        <>
               {windowsIcons.map((icons)=>{
            const {id, name , img ,url} =icons
            return(
                <div className='windows__icon' >
                  <li className='windows__list' key={id}>
                    <a href={url}>
                     <img className='windows__image' src={img}/>                                                        
                     <h4 className='windows__text'>{name}</h4>                   
                    </a>
                  </li>     
                </div>          
            )
        })}                   
        </>
    )
}
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue

In the reducer you are setting the initial state to your data list.
This is all correct.

However, then in your `Show` component you are directly importing `windowsIcons` and looping over it to render. So you are no longer looping over the state the reducer is handling. If the state changes, you won't see it.

### Solution

In your Show component instead loop over the state that you have in the reducer:

```
const { remove, icons } = useGlobalContext()

{icons.map((unin) => {
  // Render stuff
}
```

Now if you click remove it will modify the internal state and the `icons` variable will get updated.

[Codesandbox working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-monad-1ng3j?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: It works to some extent, Imagine you have a navbar, it has toggle function , and outsideClick function. So everytime I click on remove button, that navbar closes and I dont want that. I added/updated the code  the App component where I rendered the Show Component

Comment: That was not part of the original question. *...the problem is that when I click on button in Show Component it should remove the item/id of data.js in Windows Component and in Show Component, but when I click on it nothing happens...* My answer solves the problem of removing the item from the state in your context.